# How can I run a .sh to with an icon.desktop in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, scripts

I have a script that I need to run with an icon from the desktop ... suggestions? ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using only the file manager :

- first create a link to your script on your desktop (copy, then ctrl/right-click + link here)
- then, right-click on the script on the desktop, choose property : on the "general" tab, the icon is clickable. Click on it, it will open a window where you can choose your icon (look into usr/share/icons to find more icons)
- In the "permission" tab, chech the "Execution" box to allow the program to be launched.

Comment: A link cannot be set executable - it inherits the properties of the target. You have to make sure that your script itself is set executable.

Answer (score 0):

First create a `.desktop` file. You can create it in `~/.local/share/applications` for personal use or `/usr/share/applications` for all users. For example, if you want to create it for personal use, you can open a terminal and type:

```bash
vim ~/.local/share/applications/myapp.desktop
```

Second edit the `.desktop` file. Paste the following text into the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=<Your Application Name>
Exec=<Path to your .sh file>
Icon=<Path to your icon>
```

Replace `<Your Application Name>`, `<Path to your .sh file>`, and `<Path to your icon>` with the name of your application, the path to your `.sh` file, and the path to your icon respectively.

Finally save and close the file. Now you should be able to see your application in the applications menu with your custom icon.

Please note that the `Terminal=true/false` line determines whether the terminal opens a window and displays output or runs in the background1. If you want the script to execute in the background, you can set `Terminal=false`.

Remember to give execute permissions to your `.sh` file if you haven’t done so already. You can do this by running `chmod +x /path/to/your/script.sh` in the terminal.